# Why was my question migrated?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954297/how-to-write-getitem-cleanly) a few days ago.  Shortly after I placed a bounty on it (due to low attention), it was migrated to Stack Overflow, with no comment or anything (and, weirdly enough, the bounty was refunded despite bounties being "non-refundable under any circumstances," but I digress).  Without any sort of explanation, I find it difficult to determine why it was inappropriate for Programmers.  It strikes me as more of a design than a coding question, though it does have elements of both.

Presumably, there was a valid reason for the migration.  Under that assumption, what did I do wrong?  Why was Programmers a poor choice of venue for this question?

Comment: related: [I get more and better attention on Stackoverflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7104/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being the first one to cast a vote to migrate the question, my reasoning for the vote was thus:

- There was no bounty on the question at that time (the history shows that it was removed earlier by a moderator), so that didn't play a role.
- The question looked to me more of an implementation issue (how to best implement this specific behavior) than a design question.
- The question only has language tags. In my experience, questions with only a single tag specifying a language (or, as in this case, multiple tags all specifying the same language) are in the vast majority questions that are better suited for Stack Overflow.